# i3 dmenu does not browse $PATH

Tags: i3, dmenu

I want to run a shell script `~/.local/bin/test.sh` via `dmenu`. If I run `dmenu` via `$mod+D` and browse for the entry `test.sh` I couldn't find it.

The path `~/.local/bin` is already set to my `$PATH` variable in `~/.profile`

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I also removed `~/.cache/dmenu_run` and restart i3. What can I do to launch the test script via dmenu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delete `~/.cache/dmenu_run` or `~/dmenu_cache`, depending on which you have, and log back in. After your PATH is reloaded from .profile after logging in, dmenu should regenerate the cache from $PATH. dmenu seems to be bad about renewing its own cache, and needs to be forced to do it sometimes.

Also check that you have enabled the executable bit for script:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/bin/test.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user group 152 Jan 11 04:09 /home/user/.local/bin/test.sh
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already removed `~/.cache/dmenu_run` and restart the i3 but it doesn't affects the behavior of `dmenu`.

Comment: @Hölderlin It's important that you logout, and log back in to reload `~/.profile`

Comment: This may be a manjaro-only thing (it comes with a custom dmenu), but you may also have to remove the`~/.cache/dmenu-recent` directory.

Answer (score 6):

I post the full algorithm:

1. Place env vars in `~/.profile` or `~/.xprofile` (Create if doesn't exist), not in `~/.bashrc`
2. `rm -f ~/.cache/dmenu_run`
3. Log out and log in

To debug env vars type:

1. In dmenu: `echo $PATH > /tmp/path`
2. In terminal: `cat /tmp/path`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

[This Arch Linux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127056) describes the problem:

> Setting $PATH in ~/.bashrc doesn't ensure your WM/dmenu will inherit this env.
>   A more relevant question to ask is, "How do you login?" Usually the env exported in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile are available in your X applications.
>   Launch dmenu_run as you normally do, then in dmenu, type
>   `echo $PATH > /tmp/path`
>   Then in a terminal, `cat /tmp/path` to see what that $PATH is.

In my case, $PATH directories set in my `~/.profile` weren't picked up by dmenu. My window manager is started from .xinitrc, and adding an additional `export PATH=$PATH:/dir/of/interest` in the .xinitrc file before the `exec my_wm` line fixed the problem. It is a bit clunky though.

As noted previously, I had to remove the `~/.cache/dmenu_run` file and log in again after making the change to get it to work.

Comment: For some trying `echo $SHELL > /tmp/shell` could also be worth it. I thought mine was using `bash` but it turns out it used `zsh` so it checked different config files. Also tried putting it in `xinitrc` and `i3` config but neither of those worked - but /etc/zprofile did! The local ~/.zshrc was not enough. `/etc/profile` may work as well in both `zsh` and `bash`.

Comment: In my case it was not `xinitrc` but `~/.xsession`

Comment: How do you work out which .xsession or .bashrc or zprofile is what's needed? I've added a lot in a similar issue and unable to work out which - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739031/sways-dmenu-not-finding-path

Comment: @andrewjamesbowen I added a comment to your question as well, but where is your window manager being launched from? I've migrated to sway since answering this question, and sway is launched from my `~/.profile` file. I update my `$PATH` **before** sway is launched

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to fix this, but the only one that worked for me
In ~/.config/i3/config replace

```
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id dmenu_run
```

with

```
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id "export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH; dmenu_run"
```

After `rm ~/.cache/dmenu_run && i3-msg reload` binaries from ~/.local/bin accessible from dmenu